# Count the number of permutation that every entry in its permutation inversion appears at most twice

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**Problem**

A *permutation inversion* $b_1 b_2 \ldots b_n$ of the permutation $a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n$ is obtained by letting $b_j$ be the number of elements to the right of $j$ that are less than $j$, i.e. $b_j$ is the number of inversions whose first component is $j$.

For example, the permutation
$$591826473$$
has the permutation inversion
$$000142157.$$

How to count the number of permutation of length $n$ that every entry in its permutation inversion appears at most twice?

For example, the permutation inversion of $591826473$ is $000142157$, and "$0$" appears $3$ times, so this doesn't count. However, the permutation inversion of $781359642$ is $001122663$, which is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Inversion sequence* is the standard terminology for $b_1\dots b_n$ as defined in your question. The answer to your question is given in a paper by [Martinez and Savage](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.05434.pdf), see section 3.1. The number of such inversion sequences is the Euler number, [A000111](https://oeis.org/A000111).